# python - SQLAlchemy: how to get all items that are not related to current user?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

I have purpose to **get all `CourseModel` items thet are not attended by the student**. The student is picked up by `id` and is an instance of `StudentModel`. Both tables are linked through a table `attending` as Many-to-Many relationship.

```py
attending = db.Table('attending',
                     db.Column('student_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('students.id')),
                     db.Column('course_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('courses.id')))

class StudentModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "students"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String())
    last_name = db.Column(db.String())
    courses = db.relationship('CourseModel', secondary=attending, backref=db.backref('students_on_course', lazy='dynamic'))

class CourseModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "courses"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    course_name = db.Column(db.String(), unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.Text())
```

For example, we have next data:

```
      CourseModel                     attending
    ----------------            ----------------------
    id   course_name            student_id   course_id
    ----------------            ----------------------
     1   Biology                    1            1
     2   Math                       1            3
     3   Philosophy
     4   Design
```

The result for student with `id == 1` should be [(2, "Math"), (4, "Design")]

I apologize for not showing all solutions that I tried, because there are a lot of them and none of them brought me closer to my goal. My main concept is below.

```
available_courses = (db.session
                     .query(CourseModel)
                     .join(attending)
                     .join(StudentModel)
                     .filter(StudentModel.id == student_id)
                     .where(StudentModel.courses is None)  # can't find working condition for this place
                     )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery to gather the attended courses and then use that in a filter to get the missing courses:

```py
from sqlalchemy.sql import select, not_
attended_courses_subq = select(attending.c.course_id).filter(attending.c.student_id == 1)
available_courses = session.query(CourseModel).filter(not_(CourseModel.id.in_(attended_courses_subq))).all()
```

Comment: Ian, I appreciate your answer and now going to compare with mine to find best practice.

Comment: I will use your subquery and my query. It's cool!

Answer (score 0):

Congrats for me, I've got it! This works pretty good!

```
attended_courses = (db.session.query(attending.c.course_id)
                    .join(StudentModel)
                    .filter(StudentModel.id == student_id)
                    .subquery())
available_courses = (db.session
                    .query(CourseModel)
                    .filter(CourseModel.id.notin_(attended_courses))
                    .all())
```